# How to discover axis2 web service with WSO2 Governance Registry?

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

My question if is it possible to discover or integrate axis2 web services with WSO2 Governance Registry?

I want to discover all the web services and automatically upload their info to the WSO2 GREG, and check automatically if there is a new web services.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with WSO2 Greg and Application server. Here are the steps you required.

1. In jenkins(or any other task scheduler to check available services frequentrly) we will deployed scheduled task to trigger some event periodically.
2. Periodic task will call WSO2 App Server’s admin services to get service metadata. To list service meta data for axis2 services we can call service admin soap service (https://127.0.0.1:9443/services/ServiceAdmin?wsdl)
   In same way we can call all services and get complete service data(if you need other service types in addition to axis2 services).
3. Then we can call [registry rest API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance520//Registry+REST+API) and push that information.
   Please refer [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance520//Registry+REST+API) article for more information about Registry REST API.

You can find detailed description and soap service details in this [article](http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2016/08/how-to-create-axis2-service-repository.html).

[image]